# Workaround for excluding a table in streaming replication in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-replication

I have 2 database nodes working as master-slave which streaming replication in place. In one of our use cases, we require to exclude a table from getting replicated to slave. Is there a way or a workaround to exclude a table from getting copied to slave if I have to stay on this WAL based streaming replication

Comment: Not possible with streaming replication. You would need to switch to logical replication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using physical replication.  You could create a role on the master with no privs to this table, then only allow that role to connect on the replica.  This would require you to trust the admin of the replica to respect your wishes, and it wouldn't help if the goal is to reduce the size of the replica.